# Rendering eyelashes with UV mapped texture

Tags: rendering, uv, blender-internal-render-engine, transparency

I have 4 meshes for eyelashes on a head model.  I have an eyelash image texture with the typical white alpha layer mask.  How do I get Blender to render the eyelashes so they look like eyelashes instead of eyelash meshes with white eyelashes on them (see image)?  Blender refuses to use the alpha mask and instead treats it like that mask layer is a diffuse/primary image layer. I select "use alpha" and all other settings I can find that mention alpha layer but no matter what, the eyelashes always render as sheet meshes with white eyelash patterns on them.

[image]

Comment: do you use Blender Internal render engine?

Comment: Correction, I have it set to cycles.

Comment: do you have that problem in rendered mode?

Comment: The eyelashes appear white/wrong no matter what mode I use.  The alpha layer mask is displayed instead of the brown eyelashes that should show through the mask.  There's no transparency.  The entire eyelash mesh is visible instead of JUST eyelashes.